# Error unknown error: missing or invalid 'entry.level' while executing Nigthwatch.js

Tags: linux, selenium, ubuntu, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

Hello I am trying to run a basic test onto my stagin environment. Same generic test works on google but does not work in my staging environment. Here is the test :

```
browser.url('https://google.com')
.execute(function () {

    alert('this works');

});
```

When I run this test onto my personal environment, I get this error :

```
Running:  Test Project Play
INFO Request: POST /wd/hub/session 
 - data:  {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","javascriptEnabled":true,"acceptSslCerts":true,"platform":"ANY","chromeOptions":{"args":["ignore-certificate-errors","disable-web-security","ignore-certificate-errors"]},"name":"Test Project Play"}} 
 - headers:  {"Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Content-Length":245}
INFO Response 200 POST /wd/hub/session (1592ms) { status: 0,
  sessionId: '104d0fe3600f4da9b8deddf0adc06b42',
  value: 
   { applicationCacheEnabled: false,
     rotatable: false,
     mobileEmulationEnabled: false,
     networkConnectionEnabled: false,
     chrome: 
      { chromedriverVersion: '2.29.461571 (8a88bbe0775e2a23afda0ceaf2ef7ee74e822cc5)',
        userDataDir: '/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.UszN4c' },
     takesHeapSnapshot: true,
     pageLoadStrategy: 'normal',
     databaseEnabled: false,
     handlesAlerts: true,
     hasTouchScreen: false,
     version: '64.0.3282.186',
     platform: 'Linux',
     browserConnectionEnabled: false,
     nativeEvents: true,
     acceptSslCerts: true,
     locationContextEnabled: true,
     webStorageEnabled: true,
     browserName: 'chrome',
     takesScreenshot: true,
     javascriptEnabled: true,
     cssSelectorsEnabled: true,
     unexpectedAlertBehaviour: '',
     'webdriver.remote.sessionid': '104d0fe3600f4da9b8deddf0adc06b42' } }
INFO Got sessionId from selenium 104d0fe3600f4da9b8deddf0adc06b42
INFO Request: POST /wd/hub/session/104d0fe3600f4da9b8deddf0adc06b42/url 
 - data:  {"url":"https://app.bespotful.com/player/6940"} 
 - headers:  {"Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Content-Length":47}
INFO Response 200 POST /wd/hub/session/104d0fe3600f4da9b8deddf0adc06b42/url (3064ms) { sessionId: '104d0fe3600f4da9b8deddf0adc06b42',
  status: 13,
  value: { message: 'unknown error: cannot determine loading status\nfrom unknown error: missing or invalid \'entry.level\'\n  (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.186)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461571 (8a88bbe0775e2a23afda0ceaf2ef7ee74e822cc5),platform=Linux 4.13.0-36-generic x86_64)' } }
LOG     → Completed command url (3068 ms)
INFO Request: POST /wd/hub/session/104d0fe3600f4da9b8deddf0adc06b42/execute 
 - data:  {"script":"var passedArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0); return function () {\n\n            alert('this works');\n\n        }.apply(window, passedArgs);","args":[]} 
 - headers:  {"Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Content-Length":177}
ERROR Response 500 POST /wd/hub/session/104d0fe3600f4da9b8deddf0adc06b42/execute (296ms) { value: 
   { message: 'java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)',
     error: 'unknown error' },
  status: 13 }
LOG     → Completed command execute (298 ms)
INFO FINISHED
No assertions ran.
```

I am suspecting it to be cors or ssl issue but cannot confirm.

Thanks for any leads. If I find the answer I will post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it all :

```
INFO Response 200 POST /wd/hub/session/104d0fe3600f4da9b8deddf0adc06b42/url (3064ms) { sessionId: '104d0fe3600f4da9b8deddf0adc06b42',
  status: 13,
  value: { message: 'unknown error: cannot determine loading status\nfrom unknown error: missing or invalid \'entry.level\'\n  (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.186)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461571 (8a88bbe0775e2a23afda0ceaf2ef7ee74e822cc5),platform=Linux 4.13.0-36-generic x86_64)' } }
```

It is clear from your error stack trace that the **Chrome Browser Session** is not getting initialized.

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using *chromedriver=2.29*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.29*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.29/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v56-58**

- You are using *chrome=64.0*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.35*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v62-64**

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver v2.29* and the *Chrome Browser v64.0*

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  recent levels [**chromedriver=2.36**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).
- Upgrade *ChromeBrowser* to  recent levels **chrome=65.x**.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *ChromeBrowser* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *ChromeBrowser*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got miss led on the nightwatch github page as many people were complaining that chromedriver was not working and the proposed solution was to bump down the version of the chromedriver. Next time I encounter similar problem I will double check the chromedriver beffore jumping on stack overflow. Thanks